# How to fix this function? I've already defined it but it still won't work

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am trying to use the function for asking for the width and length, of something calculating the area. But it always says error.

```
# defining functions
def space(length, width):
    """ This function will calculate the area of floor, that needs 
    flooring. """
    
    # asking for variables
    length =int(input('Please enter the length of the room in meters: '))
    width =int(input('Please enter the width of the room in meters: '))
    
    area=length*width
    return area

print('Flooring for the Future ')

space(length, width)

print('Types of Flooring')
print('                Cost per sq.m.')
print('1. Low Pile Carpet     $18.75')
print('2. Shag Rug            $11.05')
print('3. Parquet             $14.35')
print('4. Lineleum            $10.40')
print('5. Hardwood            $28.15')
print()

opt=input('Please select type of flooring: ')
```

I already defined but it still says error.
The error is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File"main.py", line 29 in <module>
    space(length, width)
NameError: name 'length' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to decide if you are passing `length` and `width` to `space` or not passing them and then getting them in `space` with `input`. Most likely you want to move the `# asking for variables` lines to outside of the function

Comment: `length` is not defined in the scope *outside* of the function. nothing is wrong with your function except that you're not calling it correctly. if you're requesting user input for the length, don't use it as a function argument -- there's no need, right? in that case you'd call it like this: `space()`.

Comment: Many are suggesting that you change `space(length, width)` to `space()`. This is the wrong approach in my opinion. your method should accept parameters but you should not prompt for those values inside your method. Those prompts should be done right before you call the method.

Answer (score 1):

This one is quite simple, you are calling `space(length, width)` but `length` nor `width` have been declared, what you can do is just remove the arguments from space leaving it like this `space()` because it is inside this function where you actually assign this variables.

The final code would look something like this:

```
# defining functions
def space():
    """ This function will calculate the area of floor, that needs 
    flooring. """
    
    # asking for variables
    length =int(input('Please enter the length of the room in meters: '))
    width =int(input('Please enter the width of the room in meters: '))
    
    area=length*width
    return area

print('Flooring for the Future ')

space()

print('Types of Flooring')
print('                Cost per sq.m.')
print('1. Low Pile Carpet     $18.75')
print('2. Shag Rug            $11.05')
print('3. Parquet             $14.35')
print('4. Lineleum            $10.40')
print('5. Hardwood            $28.15')
print()

opt=input('Please select type of flooring: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to pass variables that aren't declared, into a function

`space(length, width)`

When you call this function you are passing the parameters length and width yet they are not yet defined

I would also like to mention that you need not pass any variables, so it need not be applied.

I already see that someone has answered this, but I would like to add that when you return the variable, it is not being assigned to anything

`area = space()`

This should hopefully fix your problems!

Answer (score 0):

You passing values to function that are not yet defined

```
def space( ):


     length =int(input('Please enter the length of the room in meters: '))
     width =int(input('Please enter the width of the room in meters: '))

     area=length*width
     return area

space()
```